# Glassfish - JMS Request/Response - message doesn't go on queue

Tags: web-services, glassfish, jms, openmq

I'm trying to implement a web service in Glassfish 3.1.2, using the included OpenMQ JMS queue, that implements a synchronous JMS Request-Response using Temporary queuing for the response. It sends a message that is picked up off the main queue by a remote client job (runs outside of container), and receives back a response on the temporary queue.

In a basic Java POC, this works. But once I put the server-side code into the container, it doesn't work.

I turned off the job so that the messages would just go to the queue and not be picked up, and I follow the queue with QBrowser.

If I simply send the message from the producer, **it gets onto the queue and could be read by the job.**

But once I add in the code to receive() the response, **the message is not readable on the queue.** QBrowser says that there is 1 message on the queue, but it is marked UnAck and the queue appears empty (e.g. message is not readable).

connectionFactory and requestQueue are injected as @Resource from glassfish. Main queue is defined in glassfish.

Web Service innards:

```
connection = connectionFactory .createConnection();
connection.start();

session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(requestQueue);
producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

MyObject myObj=new MyObject();
Message message=session.createObjectMessage(myObj);

TemporaryQueue responseQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(responseQueue);

message.setJMSReplyTo(responseQueue);

producer.send(message);

//if I comment out the next line, the message appears on the queue. If I leave it in, it will behave as described above.
Message response=consumer.receive();
```

I've tried various approaches, including separate connections and sessions and asynchronous consumer, and attempted a Transacted session for the producer but only got stacktraces when trying to commit.

What am I missing to make this get to the queue properly?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Domain.xml references for ConnectionFactory and Queue:

```
<connector-connection-pool description="Connection factory for job processing" name="jms/MyJobs" 
    resource-adapter-name="jmsra" connection-definition-name="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" 
    transaction-support=""></connector-connection-pool>
<connector-resource pool-name="jms/MyJobs" jndi-name="jms/MyJobs"></connector-resource>
<admin-object-resource res-adapter="jmsra" res-type="javax.jms.Queue"
   description="Queue to request a job process" jndi-name="jms/MyJobRequest">
   <property name="Name" value="MyJobRequest"></property>
</admin-object-resource>

[...]

  <resource-ref ref="jms/MyJobs"></resource-ref>
  <resource-ref ref="jms/MyJobRequest"></resource-ref>
```

Comment: I have never tried using Queue. I can help with an example using Topic, but it's really similar to yours! Maybe the problem is in the definition of the JMS resources in GlassFish. Can you post them?

Comment: Edited the domain.xml definitions in. Thanks!

Comment: Turned out to be a Transactional issue. Got around it by adding a new method: @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
 private void sendMessage(MessageProducer producer, Message message) throws Exception{
  producer.send(message);
 }

Comment: Great. You can answer to your own question so that it's available for other

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a Transactional issue.

Got around it by adding a new method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class) 
private void sendMessage(MessageProducer producer, Message message) throws Exception{   
         producer.send(message); 
}
```